# Javascript - setInterval() still running after clearInterval() called

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm making a game with Javascript. I have functions for moving left, right, gravity and down. The gravity function makes the player's location go to the bottom of the screen once it goes off the platform (div). When the gravity() function is called when you are moving right (OnButtonDownr()) it stops the move  up from working. What I mean is that when I go right and off the platform and then try to go up it doesn't work but I can go up before I go off the platform. When I try to go up (and it doesn't work) it has a weird effect which looks like its position is being set to 0 but moving up at the same time. My code:

**HTML (index.htm):**

```
<html>
<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'></head>
<body>


<div id='level' class='level'>
    <div class='start_platform' id='plat1'></div>
    <div class='platform' style='

                                 '></div>
</div>


    <img id='player' src='img/player.png' style='height:64px;'></img>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <button id='moveleft' onmousedown="OnButtonDownl (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpl (this)"><--</button>
        <button id='moveup' onmousedown="OnButtonDownu (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpu (this)">^</button>
        <button id='moveright' onmousedown="OnButtonDownr (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpr (this)">--></button>
    </div>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/move.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gravity.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS (move.js):**

```
//move left
var elem = document.getElementById("player");
function OnButtonDownl (button) {
  var posl = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10) || 0;
window.idl = setInterval(framel, 5);
function framel() {
    posl--;
    elem.style.left = posl + 'px';
    gravityCheck();
}}
function OnButtonUpl (button) {
    clearInterval(idl);
}

//move right
var elem = document.getElementById("player");
function OnButtonDownr (button) {
var posr = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10) || 0;
window.idr = setInterval(framer, 5);
function framer() {
    posr++;
    elem.style.left = posr + 'px';
    gravityCheck();
}}
function OnButtonUpr (button) {
    clearInterval(idr);
}

//move up
var elem = document.getElementById("player");
function OnButtonDownu () {
var posu = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.bottom, 10) || 0;
window.idu = setInterval(frameu, 5);
elem.style.bottom = 0;
function frameu() {
    gravity = false;
    posu++;
    elem.style.bottom = posu + 'px';
}}
function OnButtonUpu (button) {
    clearInterval(idu);
}
```

**JS (gravity.js):**

```
var gravity = true;
function gravityCheck() {
var player = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10) || 0;
var plat1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("plat1").style.left, 10) || 0;

var width = player - plat1;

    var elem = document.getElementById("player");
    var pos = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.bottom, 10) || 0;
    window.id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
    if(width > 100 && width < 164) {
    if(gravity = true) {
        pos--;
        elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px';
        if(elem.style.bottom = 0) {
            clear();
        }
    }
    }
    }
function clear() {
clearInterval(id);
}}
```

How do I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be clearing properly. Before setting interval clear any previously set one.

```
if(window.idl) clearInterval(window.idl);
window.idl = setInterval(framel, 5);
```